# Functional equation about complex anlysis

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Assuming $g: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is a known function (assuming the definition
It is meaningful for or taking a value in $\infty$), use the function equation to find $f$:
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)+f\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)=g(z)
$$

I have tried to find the function value of two points：
$$\frac{z-1}{z}=\frac{1}{1-z} \Rightarrow z^{2}-z+1=0 \quad z_{1,2}=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3} i}{2}$$
But i don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: let $h(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$, then $h(h(z)) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-z}} = \frac{1-z}{-z} = \frac{z-1}{z}=1-z^{-1}$, and $h(h(h(z))) = 1-h(z)^{-1} = 1-(1-z)=z$.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: formally by substituting $1-z \to 1/w$ so $z=\frac{w-1}{w}$ we get:

$f(w)+f(1/(1-w))=g(\frac{w-1}{w})$ or renaming $f(z)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)=g(\frac{z-1}{z})$

Formally substituting $y=\frac{z-1}{z}$ so $z=\frac{1}{1-y}$ we get:

$f\left(\frac{y-1}{y}\right)+f(y)=g(\frac{1}{1-y})$ or renaming $f\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)+f(z)=g(\frac{1}{1-z})$

Now adding the three relations gives:

$2(f(z)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)+f\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right))=g(z)+g(\frac{z-1}{z})+g(\frac{1}{1-z})$ so finally one gets:

$2f(z)=g(\frac{z-1}{z})+g(\frac{1}{1-z})-g(z)$